# Haskell Cardguess Game

Tags: haskell

I am writing a Cardguess Game, where user sets the answer and lets the PC guess. For my project, the input card number is 2.

Then, I need to write the cardguess algorithm. 
I have created the card module.

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

suitchars = "CDHS"

data Rank =
    R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 |
    Jack | Queen | King | Ace
         deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

rankchars = "23456789TJQKA"

data Card = Card {suit::Suit, rank::Rank}
      deriving (Eq, Bounded)

instance Ord Card where
    compare (Card s1 r1) (Card s2 r2) =
        let suitorder = compare s1 s2
            in  if suitorder == EQ then compare r1 r2 else suitorder

instance Enum Card where
    fromEnum (Card s r) = (fromEnum s)*13 + (fromEnum r)
    toEnum n = (Card s r)
     where s = toEnum (n `div` 13)
           r = toEnum (n `mod` 13)
```

and my strategy is to separate both Suit and Rank into two parts. initial guess could be `Card Club R5`  , `Card Heart Jack`

Then I will be given the feedback, and, according to it, I will try `nextGuess`, so on so far, till getting the right answer.

I have written the `initialGuess` function.

i put the remaining cards in the `GameState`.

```
initialGuess :: Int -> ([Card], GameState)
initialGuess card_number 
     | card_number == 2   = ((Card Club R5):(Card Heart J),cardDeck)
```

and now, I need to write the `nextGuess` code.

```
nextGuess :: ([Card],GameState) -> (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int) ->([Card],GameState)
```

`(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)` is the feedback value.
How can i represent the first parameter `([Card],GameState)`, which means the previous guess cards and previous `GameState`.

Comment: You ask *“How can i represent the first parameter `([Card],GameState)`”*. I don't understand what you mean by this. Please clarify. The first parameter is a representation of *“the previous guess cards and previous `GameState`”*.

Comment: how can i get the previous cards and gamestate.. seems like a recursive

Comment: That would be the concern of the piece of code that calls `nextGuess`. As far as `nextGuess` is concerned it's just a parameter, same as `card_number` is for `initialGuess`. Is your question really about how to call `nextGuess`?

Answer (score 1):

As I don't understand your question, and you are a beginner, I am going to nitpick on some other areas of your post.

1. You have

   ```
   initialGuess card_number 
        | card_number == 2   = ((Card Club R5):(Card Heart J),cardDeck)
   ```

   Accepting that you only need `initialGuess 2` to work for now, you have the list syntax wrong. You mean either

   ```
   initialGuess card_number 
        | card_number == 2   = (Card Club R5 : Card Heart J : [], cardDeck)
   ```

   or

   ```
   initialGuess card_number 
        | card_number == 2   = ([Card Club R5, Card Heart J], cardDeck)
   ```

   They mean the same thing, but the latter is clearer.
2. You have

   ```
   instance Ord Card where
       compare (Card s1 r1) (Card s2 r2) =
           let suitorder = compare s1 s2
               in  if suitorder == EQ then compare r1 r2 else suitorder
   ```

   If you `import Data.Monoid`, you can write this more simply as

   ```
   instance Ord Card where
       compare (Card s1 r1) (Card s2 r2) = compare s1 s2 `mappend` compare r1 r2
   ```

   But better is to leave it out and ask the compiler to write it for you instead:

   ```
   data Card = Card {suit::Suit, rank::Rank}
         deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded)
   ```

   The generated `Ord` instance uses lexicographical ordering, as you require.

Comment: I mean is where can i get the previous cards and gamestate, should I create another function??

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a function that displays the guess to you, collects feedback from you, and co-ordinates calling `initialGuess` and `nextGuess` with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to read your mind here, but maybe you want something like this:

```
startGuessing guesses state = do
  feedBack <- readFeedback
  let (newGuess, newState) = nextGuess (guesses, state) feedback
  startGuessing (guesses ++ newGuess) newState

main = do
  let (guesses, state) = initialGuess 2      
  startGuessing guesses state
```