# haskell card filter

Tags: haskell

I have a group of cards

```
initialCards :: GameState
initialCards = [[Card s1 r1, Card s2 r2] | s1 <- [minBound .. maxBound]::[Suit], r1 <- [minBound.. maxBound]::[Rank], 
                                       s2 <- [minBound .. maxBound]::[Suit], r2 <- [minBound .. maxBound]::[Rank], 
                                       s1 /= s2, r1 /= r2]
```

for example , i want to keep the [Card], which have rank Suit and Diamond, 
how can i write the code.

Comment: You really need to supply more context (surrounding code) with your question and explain what you want to achieve more clearly. Please don't assume we all read and internalised your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687898/haskell-cardguess-game).

Comment: When you write a question like "how can I write the code", people are likely to say "what have you tried?" and downvote your question, maybe it would even get closed. Please re-read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and add some information about what your thoughts are.

Comment: what kind of card has a rank suit and diamonds?

Comment: @DaxFohl I'm sure Justin means _or_ looking at the context.

Answer (score 1):

You use the filter function on the list of cards and supply it with a function that maps Suits and Diamonds to True.